# (httpd) Getting some problems with Mod_security Installation

Tags: apache, ssh, putty, vps, mod-security

I'm using Webuzo on my first unmanaged VPS (CentOS 6.4,OpenVZ). I tried to install Mod_Security following this [guide](http://www.tecmint.com/protect-apache-using-mod_security-and-mod_evasive-on-rhel-centos-fedora/#comment-32474). I installed Modsecurity-apache_2.6.6 but there's a problem in Step3 that prevents me from installing OWASP Mod_Security Core Rule Set

`wget http://www.modsecurity.org/download/modsecurity-apache_2.6.6.tar.gz`

The Download address has been removed. So I found another [guide](http://blog.softlayer.com/2013/web-development-installing-mod_security-with-owasp) for the rule set but I can't get this command to work

`git clone https://github.com/SpiderLabs/owasp-modsecurity-crs.git`

It returns "-bash: git: command not found"

What command should I use to get OWASP CRS?

Also, I suspect the mod_security installation is incomplete since httpd server is unable to restart after installing modsecurity. Here's the configuration error:

`[root@xx ~]# httpd -t
Syntax error on line 7 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/modsecurity.conf:
Invalid command 'SecRuleEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration`

Should I uninstall Mod_Secuirty first since everything seems to have become a mess now?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The apache binary in case of Webuzo is located at /usr/local/apps/apache and the modules are located at /usr/local/apps/apache/modules/lib.
Also the apache configurations in case of Webuzo are located at /usr/local/apps/apache/etc/ and /usr/local/apps/apache/etc/conf.d/

It seems you are trying to compile mod_security at an inappropriate location.

Answer (score 0):

As you are having error with modsecurity.conf, I wonder whether you have followed the step

> Step 4: Configuring Mod_Security

In the [guide](http://www.tecmint.com/protect-apache-using-mod_security-and-mod_evasive-on-rhel-centos-fedora/#comment-32474) you have followed.

> "-bash: git: command not found"

This error can be resolved by installing the package that includes git. try

> yum install git-core -y

Both [guide1](http://www.tecmint.com/protect-apache-using-mod_security-and-mod_evasive-on-rhel-centos-fedora/#comment-32474) and [guide2](http://blog.softlayer.com/2013/web-development-installing-mod_security-with-owasp/) are good to install mod_sec and follow any one. :)

Comment: Thank you Leo. Something seems to prevent me from retarting httpd. I want to start everything again from the zero. How can I uninstall the files first? I've installed two different mod security files ([root@ee ModSecurity] and [modsecurity-apache_2.6.6]) from guide 1 and 2 and downloaded the security core [modsecurity-crs].

Comment: Go through the guide 1 and 2 and you have to manually revert all the changes. did you followed the step four in the guide 1. try "grep -i security2_module /etc.httpd/conf/httpd.conf" Are you having any control panels?

Comment: Yes, after editing the httpd.conf. I entered /etc/init.d/httpd restart in different locations but nothing happens. Is this normal?
- [root@ee modsecurity-crs]# vi /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf  
- [root@ee modsecurity-crs]# /etc/init.d/httpd restart  
- [root@ee modsecurity-crs]# cd  
- [root@ee ~]# /etc/init.d/httpd restart

Comment: Yes, I'm using Webuzo

Comment: Here's the result:                                                    1.I entered: [root@ee ~]# grep -i security2_module /etc.httpd/conf/httpd.conf
2.It returned: grep: /etc.httpd/conf/httpd.conf: No such file or directory

Comment: After following step 4 in guide 1, when I ran httpd -t, the new error is this:  Syntax error on line 1011 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Could not open configuration file /etc/httpd/modsecurity-apache/modsecurity.conf: No such file or directory